# Slider de Bootstrap no se agregar correctamente las imagenes?

Tags: bootstrap

Hola amigos estoy usado la version 4 de Bootstrap y estoy usando su slider y como veo use una imagen de internet solo como prueba pero no se adapta la imagen con el div completo del slider?

Alguien sabe porque?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Gilberto Quintero</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gilberto Quintero </a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Cursos</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Eres Desarrollador</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://noticias.universia.net.mx/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-sobre-programacion.jpg" width="1000" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://noticias.universia.net.mx/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-sobre-programacion.jpg"  width="" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He añadido una regla css para todos las etiquetas img con width: 100% y le he quitado un indicador del ya que solo tenias dos imagenes y en la lista tenias 3. Espero haber ayudado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Gilberto Quintero</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
  img{
width: 100%;
  }

</style>
  </head>

  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gilberto Quintero </a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Cursos</a>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Eres Desarrollador</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://noticias.universia.net.mx/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-sobre-programacion.jpg" width="1000" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://noticias.universia.net.mx/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-sobre-programacion.jpg"  width="1000" alt="Second slide">
</div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudates y buen css lo checare.